# Regular expression: page path starts with "/posts/" and ends with ".html"

Tags: regex, perl

I'm stuck here:

```
=~^/posts/(*).html
```

but it doesn't work

I need something that can recognise something like this:

```
/posts/testing.html

/posts/another-testing-issue.html
```

And I'm not very good using RegEx

Can anyone help me please?

EDIT:

Floris had the right answer:

```
^/posts/.*html$
```

thank you!

Comment: What is the `=~`? What language are you using?

Comment: hi, i'm in the Google Analytics API. If I put: =~^/posts/ it is a valid string

Comment: There is a difference between the 'regular expression', and how you use it (the language environment). The regex you want is simply `^/posts/.*html$` - but how you use it depends on the environment

Comment: @Floris *Did you collect up that 20k reputation this way?*

Comment: @revo The difference between Floris's answer and yours, and the difference between ca. 20k reputation and ca. 0.9k, have considerable to do with one another.

Comment: @AaronMiller He deleted his related side of conversation, so there's no need to reply back to your comment

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, the expression you need is

```
^\/posts\/.*\.html$
```

Explanation:

```
^          start of string
\/posts\/  literal string '/posts/' 
           the backslash "protects" the forward slash -
           it is called "escaping", and removes any special meaning it might have
           (in some applications the / would be a delimiter)                        
.*         any number of characters
\.         literal '.'
html       literal 'html'
$          end of string
```

Now for a bit more background on regex syntax…
A
s @Peter points out in the comment, a `quantifier` follows "the thing to quantify". In most (all?) regex syntaxes, writing `(*)` will generate the error `preceding token is not quantifiable`. You need something in front of the `*`, and a `(` doesn't count (unless it was escaped).

This is where the dot comes in. The dot `.` means "any character at all`.  That is its usual meaning, which is why`.*` is just about the most common thing in regular expressions, meaning "I don't care about the next bit…" (usually up to an "until" - whatever follows).

Because the dot has a special meaning, when you want the exact string `.html`, you need to write it as `\.html` (there's that escape backslash again to remove the special meaning from the dot).

As a final tweak, it is not uncommon to have an extension like `.htm` - so you could write your expression as

```
\/posts\/.*\.html?$
```

This would make the last character, the `l`, optional (the `?` means "zero or one times the preceding expression, which in this case is the single character immediately before it).

You can see this at work at http://regex101.com/r/bK5yC7 - it is a wonderful tool for exploring regular expressions, and also gives a nice explanation (breakdown) of every expression you type (with highlighting of any errors)

Comment: In addition: *,+,{n},{n-m} are quantity qualifiers. What has been missing was the information about what to quantify.

Comment: @Peter valid comment. I have updated my answer to be more explicit about that point.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `dot` as single character match and didn't escape the second one as being literal:

```
^/posts/(.*)\.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of regular expression . mean any character and * means multiplicity, so try to fix to

```
^/posts/(.*)\.html
```

\ is escape character